# Spanning the Lie Algebra of $SL_{2}(\mathbf{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

What is a sufficient criteria for testing whether or not a set of matrices span the Lie algebra of $SL_{2}(\mathbf{R})$?

Comment: Finding three linearly independent ones?

Answer (score 3):

There should be as many matrices as the algebra, be elements of the algebra and they should be linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

One condition is that they not have a common one-dimensional invariant subspace in $\mathbb C^2$.